# How do I query one table, but get related information from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

for example i have two tables:

```
posts {id,user_id,date}
design{user_id, bg_color}
```

and i have a `post id of 18` for example, i want to retrieve the design's table by the same user_id of that post(which is 18)

how can i query this?

sorry for this stupid, im confused ? :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT design.user_id, design.bg_color
FROM posts
JOIN design
  ON posts.user_id = design.user_id
WHERE posts.id = 18
```

In other words, we first select from `posts` where `id` is 18;
then we join `design` rows on which the `user_id` equals the `user_id` of the `posts` row.
We retrieve the corresponding `user_id` and `bg_color` from the `design` table.

Note that if there are multiple rows with the same design.user_id, you will get multiple rows back - example:

```
posts.id  | posts.user_id
 1           5
 3           2
 18          9


design.user_id | design.bg_color
 2                '#aaffcc'
 5                'red'
 5                'blue'
 9                '#000000'
 9                '#cafe00'
```

query result:

```
posts.id | posts.user_id | design.user_id | design.bg_color
 18         9               9                '#000000'
 18         9               9                '#cafe00'
```

Comment: @getaway: In that case, you'll only get one row back :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT design.*
  FROM design
  JOIN posts on posts.user_id = design.user_id
 where posts.ID = 18
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?:

```
SELECT design.*
FROM design
    JOIN posts ON design.user_id = posts.user_id
WHERE posts.id = ?givenid
```

Keep in mind that this could, based on the information you've given us, be a many-to-one relation.  Are you looking for a single record or multiple records from the `design` table?

Comment: @getaway: More information may be required, then.  Is `user_id` the primary key for the `design` table?  If not, is it unique?

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that it's one-to-one. Can you explain how this could be many-to-one?

Comment: @Jazzerus: Very little information is given about the table structures in the question.  It's possible that there's more information we're not seeing.  If `user_id` isn't the PK for `design`, but is instead a PK on a third table unknown to us, then there could be multiple records in either of the supplied tables sharing the same `user_id`, making the results of the query less exact based on the information we have.  In that case there may not be a relation between these two tables at all, except through a third table.  Better to ask than to assume.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `design`.* FROM `design`, `posts` WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = `design`.`user_id` AND `posts`.`id` = 18
```

Comment: +1: for simpler queries, this may be easier to write than the usual JOIN form - note that it gets internally converted to the same form as @n8wrl's form (in hir answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
    select * from posts join 
design on 
posts.user_id=design.user_id 
where posts.id=18
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing, but I think this will do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` LEFT JOIN `design` USING (`user_id`) WHERE `posts`.`id` = 18
```